`idmapd` static mappings ignored in kerberized nfs share, but permissions are enforced correctly
Apologies for posting yet another kerberos+nfs rambling.
TLDR: kerberized nfs shares from servers in different domains are mounted succesfully, but local username is not mapped correctly, despite enforcing correct permissions when creating files

I have 2 kerberized nfs shares mounted on a debian client, served from different hosts in separate domains, and both are supposed to be mapped to local (client) account anon.
For reference, client is anonpc.lab.lan (domain LAB.LAN), the shares are from hosts nas.lab.lan (same domain) and nas.site.lan (different domain, SITE.LAN).
The principals in use are anon@LAB.LAN and anon@SITE.LAN, I can kinit them both just fine and the subsequent output of klist -A is as expected.
The kerberos config itself has been quite painful to get, but I'm at a point where both shares mount "successfully".
Host principals are initialized in machine credentials cache of both domains, and running ls -la shows the correct directory contents in both shares.
Running a simple touch shareLAB/test.txt and touch shareSITE/test.txt result in the file being created, and checking on both servers the files have the correct user set.
The problem is the username mapping in the client, and I attempted many different configurations for /etc/idmapd.conf (on anonpc.lab.lan) without really getting it.

This is the krb5.conf config:
anon@anonpc:~$ cat /etc/krb5.conf
[libdefaults]

# Keep default_realm as ANYTHING other than any of the domains used below
# NOTE: for example setting to `LAB.LAN` will make `rpc-gssd` always attempt to work in this realm,
#       ignoring both the actual domain and the definitions below.
#       If left empty, `gssd` does not even attempt appending the host domain to its request
default_realm = LOCAL

# Set up ccache in a directory instead of single file
# Allows for `kinit` in multiple domains, then `klist -A` to see all
default_ccache_name = DIR:/tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}

[realms]
LAB.LAN = {
  kdc = kdc.lab.lan
  admin_server = kdc.lab.lan
}
SITE.LAN = {
  kdc = kdc.site.lan
  admin_server = kdc.site.lan
}

[domain_realm]
lab.lan = LAB.LAN
.lab.lan = LAB.LAN
site.lan = SITE.LAN
.site.lan = SITE.LAN

Here's how it looks like when both user principals are kinited.
# init both principals
anon@anonpc:~$ kinit anon@LAB.LAN && kinit anon@SITE.LAN
...

# check credentials cache
anon@anonpc:~$ klist -A
Ticket cache: DIR::/tmp/krb5cc_1000/tkt123456
Default principal: anon@SITE.LAN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  krbtgt/SITE.LAN@SITE.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01

Ticket cache: DIR::/tmp/krb5cc_1000/tkt654321
Default principal: anon@LAB.LAN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/30/2024 00:00:01  krbtgt/LAB.LAN@LAB.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01

We can also check there's no machine credentials cache initialized yet.
anon@anonpc:~$ sudo klist -A
[NO OUTPUT]
anon@anonpc:~$ sudo klist /tmp/krb5ccmachine_LAB.LAN
klist: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5ccmachine_LAB.LAN)
anon@anonpc:~$ sudo klist /tmp/krb5ccmachine_SITE.LAN
klist: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5ccmachine_SITE.LAN)

Let's attempt mounting both shares (please note mount is run as user anon and without elevated privileges), and check klist -A again:
anon@anonpc:~$ mount shareLAB && mount shareSITE
[SUCCESS MOUNTING BOTH SHARES]

anon@anonpc:~$ ls -la shareLAB shareSITE
[DIRECTORY CONTENTS AS EXPECTED]

anon@anonpc:~$ klist -A
Ticket cache: DIR::/tmp/krb5cc_1000/tkt123456
Default principal: anon@SITE.LAN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  krbtgt/SITE.LAN@SITE.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  nfs/nas.site.lan@SITE.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01

Ticket cache: DIR::/tmp/krb5cc_1000/tkt654321
Default principal: anon@LAB.LAN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  krbtgt/LAB.LAN@LAB.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  nfs/nas.lab.lan@LAB.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01

Same goes for machine credentials:
anon@anonpc:~$ sudo klist -A
[NO OUTPUT]

anon@anonpc:~$ sudo klist /tmp/krb5ccmachine_LAB.LAN
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_LAB.LAN
Default principal: nfs/anonpc.lab.lan@LAB.LAN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  krbtgt/LAB.LAN@LAB.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  nfs/nas.lab.lan@LAB.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01

anon@anonpc:~$ sudo klist /tmp/krb5ccmachine_SITE.LAN
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_SITE.LAN
Default principal: nfs/anonpc.lab.lan@SITE.LAN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  krbtgt/SITE.LAN@SITE.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01
07/30/2024 00:00:01  07/31/2024 00:00:01  nfs/nas.site.lan@SITE.LAN
    renew until 07/31/2024 00:00:01

This should confirm that principals are initialized and used for both shares.
Also please note that the default machine principal for SITE.LAN is still resolved to nfs/anonpc.lab.lan (note the lab.lan domain), which means I explicitly created a dedicated host principal with the FQDN of the client joined to the first domain in the second domain's kdc (also something I'd like to avoid if anybody can help).

Now to the idmapd.conf problem.
Both servers are configured with the correct Domain value, e.g. nas.lab.lan has Domain = LAB.LAN.
Where I'm failing is the debian client config.
The first attempt was leaving it largely untouched, other than ensuring I'm not setting any default realm just like with krb5.conf:
anon@anonpc:~$ cat /etc/idmapd.conf
[General]
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
Domain = local

[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup

[Translation]
Method = nsswitch

but after applying this configuration with service nfs-idmapd restart && nfsidmap -c and mounting the shares, neither shows the correct user. In fact, both are mounted as nobody:4294967294.
I figured ok let's try to add static mappings:
...
[Translation]
Method = nsswitch,static

[Static]
anon@LAB.LAN = anon
anon@SITE.LAN = anon

but nope, same uid:gid of nobody:4294967294 for both shares.
I though nsswitch must be getting in the way, since the same username is mapped to two different domains it must assume they are not the same local user, so I edited the config to ensure nsswitch is not being used:
...
[Translation]
Method = static
...

and finally something changes, but for the worse. Now both shares are mounted as root:root.
This tells me that the static mappings are being completely ignored, and I suspect because I'm not defining them properly.
If I set up auditd to log all kernel calls to nfsidmap and then check the messages, I can see the correct strings are being passed around (field a4=...):
# config auditd
anon@anonpc:~$ sudo auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/usr/sbin/nfsidmap

# check logs
anon@anonpc:~$ sudo journalctl -f --grep EXECVE
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="123456789a" a4="uid:anon@lab.lan"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="123456789b" a4="gid:anon@lab.lan"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="123456789c" a4="uid:root@lab.lan"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="123456789d" a4="gid:root@lab.lan"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="123456789e" a4="uid:nobody"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="123456789f" a4="gid:nogroup"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="1234567890" a4="uid:anon@site.lan"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="1234567891" a4="gid:anon@site.lan"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="1234567892" a4="uid:root@site.lan"
Jul 30 00:00:10 anonpc audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="nfsidmap" a1="-t" a2="600" a3="1234567893" a4="gid:root@site.lan"

And checking the identities known to nfsidmap seems to yield sane results:
anon@anonpc:~$ sudo nfsidmap -l
10 .id_resolver keys found:
  uid:anon@site.lan
  gid:root@site.lan
  uid:root@site.lan
  gid:nogroup
  uid:nobody
  gid:root@lab.lan
  uid:root@lab.lan
  gid:anon@lab.lan
  uid:anon@lab.lan
  gid:anon@site.lan

So as last ditch attempts I tried matching these values, first changing the [Static] mappings to domains in lower case (e.g. anon@LAB.LAN = anon to anon@lab.lan = anon), then adding the uid: prefix (e.g. uid:anon@lab.lan = anon).
It did not change the results.

With all the attempts described above, I can always successfully touch a file in both shares running the command as user anon.
And despite being shown mounted as root:root I do not need elevated privileges, and the new file created on both servers is correctly mapped to user anon.
So this appears to be a cosmetic issue, because the actual permissions enforced are those I would expect.
If I try to create a new file from a different (local) user john (at anonpc.lab.lan), the command fails with Permission denied as expected, and trying the same with sudo does not change the outcome.
Again, please note that this is what happens for both shares in all previous idmapd.conf examples.
There is always the wrong uid:gid shown, but correct permissions are applied.

The only config which gets me halfway there is setting the Domain section of [General] to either of the two domains.
For example this super basic config:
anon@anonpc:~$ cat /etc/idmapd.conf
[General]
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
Domain = LAB.LAN

[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup

correctly maps user anon to the share from nas.lab.lan, while the other mounted share remains mapped to nobody:4294967294.
Same happens in reverse, if Domain = SITE.LAN the user is correctly mapped only on the relative share from nas.site.lan.
Needless to say, adding and enabling static mappings on top of this config does not fix the issue.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it a simple syntax error?
Why are idmapd static mappings being ignored?
